# How to change the URL/route from within an observer

Tags: ember.js

How can I force the application to change the URL/route when something happens that is triggered by an observer in a controller?

Comment: Where's your code, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [transitionToRoute](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute):

```
// controllers/item.js

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
     myObserver: function() {
          if(this.get('someProperty')) {
               this.transitionToRoute('someOtherRoute');
          }
     }.observes('someProperty')
});
```